# How to run function when embedded Surveymonkey is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, surveymonkey

I'm using an embedded Surveymonkey survey using a `script` tag and giving the tag a link to the widget that Surveymonkey creates. At the end of the survey, users can click a "done" button which sends the results to Surveymonkey, but I want to call another function when the user presses done.

I tried using `document.getElementsByClassName()`, but when I console log the result, I just get an empty HTML Collection.

I tried giving the script tag an id and used `document.getElementById` to get the script tag, but when I print the result, I just get the script tag and can't access the innerHTML event after writing `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Great question. I love how specific you are.